# What and where is "vmath.h"?

Tags: c++, math, opengl

I am reading through the 8th edition of the OpenGL Programming Guide by Shreiner Sellers Kessenich and Licea-Kane, and I keep seeing this "vmath" library being used for vector and matrices work.

I did a google search for vmath.h, but wasn't able to find anything. I did a search on stackoverflow and found one question where it has been used but nothing more.

My question is where or how can I install it or download it. I assumed it was something which came along with freeglut or whatever other opengl stuff I installed with "apt-get install", but apparently not since g++ can't find vmath.h.

Any ideas on how to get it installed?

Comment: Is it: http://bartipan.net/vmath/

Comment: https://github.com/JimAllanson/scriptsbots/blob/master/vmath.h

Comment: You might want to take a look at `GLM`

Comment: @Shaktal Which one is it then?

Comment: @Griffin Which one is it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web site for the book can be found at [The OpenGL Programming Guide](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/). That page has a [link to a .zip file](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/Code/oglpg-8th-edition.zip) with most of the code from the book. The `vmath.h` file is in the `include` directory.

Answer (score 8):

@Blastfurnace provides the correct address to download. But I still have something to say.

Please use glm instead of `vmath.h`: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html

I used `vmath.h` and found tons of bugs. Some definitions of operator causes recursive function call and stack overflows. Also the conversion between radius and degree is inverted.

line 11:

```
template <typename T> 
inline T radians(T angleInRadians)
{
    return angleInRadians * static_cast<T>(180.0/M_PI);
}
```

line 631:

```
static inline mat4 perspective(float fovy /* in degrees */, float aspect, float n, float f)
{
    float  top = n * tan(radians(0.5f*fovy)); // bottom = -top
    float  right = top * aspect; // left = -right
    return frustum(-right, right, -top, top, n, f);
}
```

Obviously the tangent function accepts a radian input, but the function 'radian' converts the radian to degree instead.

line 137:

```
inline vecN& operator/=(const vecN& that)
{
    assign(*this * that);

    return *this;
}
```

It should be a division instead of a multiplication: `assign(*this / that)`.

line 153:

```
inline vecN& operator/(const T& that)
{
    assign(*this / that);
}
```

See? Recursive call of operator '/'. At least in Xcode this causes a stack overflow.

These bugs annoy me a lot, while glm library provides almost the same functions but much more stable code. I STRONGLY RECOMMEND you using glm instead of the current buggy `vmath.h`. Maybe when all these bugs are fixed, a simple `vmath.h` would be a better choice, while you need to give up at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! I was also wondering about this vmath.h and I saw people online using glm and I was wondering if these serve the same function(s) and if so which to use. Good to know!